# The CN1 Intellij Plugin is suddenly disabled on old project. Is it safe to delete an old ~/cn1Settngs/CN1Properties to fix this?

Tags: codenameone

Strange issue I'm having and I want to know what to do to fix it without compromising project integrity.

I have a CN1 project in Intellij (v 2017.1.4) that I started a long time ago.  The other day I started a new CN1 project to try out something new.  It pulled down the latest CN1 libs (the properties file says version 174 is the libVersion) and worked fine for testing.

Now I open my original project and the CodenameOne functions are all greyed out (projectLibs version in the properties file is 159).  The icon on the context menu and menu-bar are greyed out.   The plugin is up to date (3.7.2).  I see no messages or errors in the IntelliJ "messages" section.

I am assuming that the new project and libs re-wrote something common to both projects and now the old project can't even start the plugin to let it pull down new libs...   In experimenting, I went to my home directory ~/.cn1Settings and renamed the "CN1Preferences" file so that the project would have to create a new one.  When I opened the project it DID create a new one and the plugin was working.

So here's the big question:  **If I abandon my old CN1Preferences file, what settings/customizations in that file am I walking away from and will I need to make sure I set correctly again to ensure my project works as it should and doesn't have any hard to debug issues?**

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue of keeping two windows concurrently, try closing both projects and opening only one at a time. There is an issue with detecting the correct project in the IntelliJ/IDEA plugin

Comment: Thanks Shai. Back to the main question: What Data is in the .cn1Settings/CN1Preferences file that will be lost if I delete the preferences file and let CN1 re-create it? You're right: I was using multiple windows at the time (testing the Animated GIF CN1 Library you helped me with the other day).  That was the "new" project and the "older" project is the one without a working menu.   I tried opening and closing the new one (saving preferences between) and then opening the old project and still no change: Cannot access CN1 menu from the old project.  So thinking of deleting CN1Preferences...

Comment: The preferences is a part of your application and has nothing to do with the plugin. It maps to the `Preferences` API in Codename One

Comment: The Preferences I am talking about is in a folder ".codenameone" in my home directory and is updated every time I am able to open the preferences dialog.  I believe the preferences dialog stores some shared information there that is used across all codenameone projects, so again, I'll ask, do you know what data the preferences app stores in that file that I would need to re-enter if I were to blow it away and start it fresh to try getting the plugin to work again?

Comment: If you close the other windows and open only that window it should work. I doubt anything is broken because of that file. What will impact a project lies in the project directory.